# How to stop mobogenie auto-download in Android?

Tags: downloading, uninstallation, sony-xperia

mobogenie application auto download in my mobile. My cellphone is Sony Xperia J and my Android version is 4.1.2. Once, I removed it from my device, but it's downloaded automatically again. How to stop that?

Comment: Hi, I realize this is an old question, but it'd help if you could clarify the detail a little bit. By "downloading", did you mean downloading the APK file only, or downloading (and installing) from market app? Based on the answer, I'd assume the former since the APK was downloaded by rogue ads? (similar to https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-2/352043-how-stop-mobogenie-auto-download.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setting -> Accounts & Sync -> Google -> Ads( Reset the Advertising ID ) + Ads setting ( Google Ads Manager and Opt out )